# Consistently get data from action in controller with in MVC $.ajax()?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have this code in my controller:

```
int number = 0;

    public JsonResult JsonData()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
        {
            number += i;
            return Json(number, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(number, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And loop with jQuery Ajax script in the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tag = true;
$(document).ready(function () {
    while (tag) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("JsonData", "Home")",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#counter').html('');
                $('#counter').html(data);

                if (data == 20) {
                    tag = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>

<div id="counter"></div>
```

My goal is to make jQuery Ajax to constantly get "number" from action "JasonData" and print that number to "DIV tag" But my current code is not working for some reason, - the result is that browser window will not stop loading if i'm using "while()" loop, if I'm not using "while()" loop it only prints the first value of "number" variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a setInterval/setTimeout instead of while loop, because continuously running script will block the UI and you can utilize the callback mechanism instead.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("JsonData", "Home")",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#counter').html(data);
                if (data == 20) { //<-- make sure data has value 20 and is not an object or anything
                    window.clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }
        });
    }, 1000); //<-- Give interval in milliseconds here
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FQ7Dj/)**

Or with timeout:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  makeAjaxCall();
});



  function makeAjaxCall(){
         $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("JsonData", "Home")",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#counter').html(data);
                    if (+data < 20) {
                        window.setTimeout(makeAjaxCall, 1000); //Duration in ms
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e7arS/)**